# How to rewrite URL as subdomain in asp.net-core without actually creating a subdomain on dot net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Good Day All,

Is this possible to mimic URLs in .net core without actually creating a sub domain if i use Rewrite Module.

For example : URL : example.com?value=somecode

and rewrite as : somecode.example.com

Please confirm if it can be done using rewrite module.

I add bellow code for URL rewrite on startup.cs file but I want as per above example.

```
var rewrite = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite("signup", "registration", false); 
app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
```

Comment: just a naming convension? why not use MapRoute? @Bhavin?

Comment: It's easy to rewrite " example.com?value=somecode" to "somecode.example.com" with rewriter middleware. But could you please elaborate on "**without actually creating a subdomain on dot net core**"?